# psql asks for a password when username in host and postgres server are identical?

Tags: users, docker, postgresql

I have a postgres server running in a docker container. I added a user there named "myuser". I also have a linux user named "myuser".

Then (as root) I do:

```
$ su - myser
$ psql
Password for myuser:
```

My question is, why does it ask me for a password? When I ran the postgres server installed on the host (not in a docker container) it was enough that the usernames matched and I could log in without a password.

How can I log in to the psql server without supplying a password?

Comment: It has to do with the configuration in the file `pg_hba.conf` that has to be different between your distribution and the Docker container. You can find more info on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
You should add the content of that file to your question to get a more precise answer.